# TypeError: 'Human' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm new to programming, I've searched for 30 minutes as to why this is happening but don't really understand it.  I understand that my object isn't a function I guess, but I thought `__repr__` was supposed to return a string if you call  the object?

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

    def greeting(self):
        return "Nice to meet you " + self.name + "."

    def future(self):
        add20 = self.age + 20
        return "You will be " + add20 + " in 20 years!"

    def wage(self):
        if sex == "male":
            return "Nice!"
        else:
            return "Sweet"

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.greeting)


def main():
    codey = Human("Codey",22,"male")
    print(codey())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "I thought `__repr__` was supposed to return a string if you call the object" — No.  Why would you think that?

Comment: `codey`  is instance of class `Human`, not function (and it doesn't have method `__call__`) so you can't use it as function - you need `print(codey)`

Comment: I expected it to print(self.greeting)

Comment: `self.greeting` is a functiuon, but you are calling it like an attribute defined and you didn't specify a `__call__` method, that's why you can't `codey()`

Comment: `__repr__` has to return string, not print it.

Comment: So I tried the __call__ instead, but now it's printing a location in memory instead of the string?  I also tried return str(self.greeting)

Comment: The proper way to invoke `__repr__` is with the `repr()` built-in: `repr(codey)`.  And your `__repr__` implementation is broken... you need to call `self.greeting`: `print(self.greeting())` and you should really return the result, not print it.

Answer (score 2):

First: you have to use `codey` without `()`

```
print(codey)
```

Second: `__repr__` (and `__str__`) has to return string.
And `self.greeting` is method so it needs `()` to execute it (and return string).

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.greeting()
```

---

Full version:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

    def greeting(self):
        return "Nice to meet you " + self.name + "."

    def future(self):
        add20 = self.age + 20
        return "You will be " + add20 + " in 20 years!"

    def wage(self):
        if sex == "male":
            return "Nice!"
        else:
            return "Sweet"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.greeting() # <-- return instead print, function need ()


def main():
    codey = Human("Codey",22,"male")
    print(codey) # <-- without (()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I understand it now.  Puting the () after codey was calling it so it didn't know how to handle it.  Works now!